# passing arguments in constructer function in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function player(){
    this.hitpoints =100;
    this.attack = function attack(opponent){
        opponent.hitpoints -= 10;
    }
} 
var p1 = new player();
var p2 = new player();

p1.name = "ali";
p2.name = "ahmed";
p1.attack(p2);

alert(p2.name+"has"+p2.hitpoints+"left behind");
```

The output  of the above code is

> ahmed has 90 left behind.

But whenever I change my code to `p1.attack(p2.name;` instead of `p1.attack(p2);` then it will output the following result:

> ahmed has 100 left behind.

Why does it output this result?

I am a beginner in Javascript, I do not really know anything about objects.  I simply want to know how arguments should be passed in that particular `attack()` function.

Comment: Please take the time to make sure that the code in the question really is the code you're using, and use correct syntax in the text of the question. This helps make sure your question is clear.

Comment: It's because you are giving an object to `attack` method. When you give it a parameter of `p2.name`, you are giving it a string.

Comment: At this point, several different people have edited your question, and I'm **not at all** sure it actually asks what you want to ask. Please delete it and ask a question paying attention to detail. Details matter in programming, and in questions about programming.

Comment: `attack` function decrements `opponent.hitpoint` by 10. Now p1 and p2 has property `hitpoint` but `p2.name` is not an object.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder While I agree about accuracy - I think the current state of the question does reflect what the OP wanted to ask, and Cyval hits the nail on the head in his comment.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It is the same as his original just fixed up a little look at the versions...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I agree with James Thorpe he is basically asking why passing an `Object` to his method is different then passing a `String`...

Comment: @JamesThorpe: Hopefully it does. I *think* it *probably* does. But...

Comment: thx  @ rajesh and @cyval i got it so p2 is an object and p2.name is string thats a reason when i passed string it give me 100 and when i pass object i gives 90 i see but i have another question when p2 will pass in argument opponent what would be the value of object please recomend me some good examples so i could understand its concepts.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I agree with James Thorpe he is basically asking why passing an Object to his method is different then passing a String exactly this is what i really want to know. thx

Comment: @AliAlmis What do you mean by your second question? Kindly elaborate. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is because you're passing an object to the function.
Passing `p2.name` as a parameter will not work, since `p2.name` is a property with data type of string.

The operation then goes with the following parameters given:

```
attack(p2) => p2.hitpoints -= 10
attack(p2.name) => p2.name.hitpoints -=10,
```

which is not valid because p2.name is not an instance of player.

Comment: Exactly. You are trying to pass a property of the object instead of passing the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
p1.attack(p2.name)
```

then the code will try to substract 10 from `p2.name.hitpoints` and left `p2.hitpoints` intact.